# Python Program Doesn't Show Any Output/Result in Visual Studio Code (No Errors)

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I have a python program that displays no errors when I run it but doesn't give any kind of output.  It only displays:

"Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

- Serving Flask app 'Editable_Table'
- Debug mode: on"

No other output is given.  It gives the same result when I run it directly from the command line.

I tried doing some research and read that a potential problem is defining the main() function.  I don't know how to do that (ultra beginner to coding here) and everything I tried doesn't work.  I have "

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

at the end of the program, and I tried defining main() as

```
def main():
    main()
```

and switching the main() and app.run_server(debug=True) lines.

Here's the full code:

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Input(
            id='adding-rows-name',
            placeholder='Enter a column name...',
            value='',
            style={'padding': 10}
        ),
        html.Button('Add Column', id='adding-rows-button', n_clicks=0)
    ], style={'height': 50}),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='adding-rows-table',
        columns=[{
            'name': 'Column {}'.format(i),
            'id': 'column-{}'.format(i),
            'deletable': True,
            'renamable': True
        } for i in range(1, 5)],
        data=[
            {'column-{}'.format(i): (j + (i-1)*5) for i in range(1, 5)}
            for j in range(5)
        ],
        editable=True,
        row_deletable=True
    ),

    html.Button('Add Row', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0),

    dcc.Graph(id='adding-rows-graph')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    State('adding-rows-table', 'columns'))
def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({c['id']: '' for c in columns})
    return rows

@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-table', 'columns'),
    Input('adding-rows-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('adding-rows-name', 'value'),
    State('adding-rows-table', 'columns'))
def update_columns(n_clicks, value, existing_columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        existing_columns.append({
            'id': value, 'name': value,
            'renamable': True, 'deletable': True
        })
    return existing_columns


@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    Input('adding-rows-table', 'columns'))
def display_output(rows, columns):
    return {
        'data': [{
            'type': 'heatmap',
            'z': [[row.get(c['id'], None) for c in columns] for row in rows],
            'x': [c['name'] for c in columns]
        }]
    }
    
def main():
    main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to print anything else? It started the server and printed that it did that. So everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The output will actual display in your browser. Copy/paste http://127.0.0.1:8050/ into your browser window and your app will pop up.

In your current code, you don't have anything printing to the console, so nothing should be expected there.